# How to determine which version of Ubuntu desktop is installed

Tags: command-line, versions

What command is used to determine which version of Ubuntu desktop is installed?

Comment: Do you mean the version of Ubuntu (the operating system), or the [desktop environment](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/desktop_environment)?

Comment: `cat /etc/issue`

Comment: Would like to know both the version of Ubuntu (the operating system), and the desktop environment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Execute `lsb_release -a` in a terminal :

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.10
Release:        16.10
Codename:       yakkety
```

Comment: Works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

`more /etc/*-release` will give you the desired information.